# Is a string reference equality check guaranteed to be static?

Tags: c#, string

I have a function with this signature:

```
public void DoSomething(String name);
```

The string `name` is special in my application. It can be either an arbitrary string, or a special known value. Because any non-empty string value is a valid input it means I need to use object reference equality with empty strings, like so:

```
public class Foo {

    public const String SpecialValue1 = "";
    public const String SpecialValue2 = "";

    public void DoSomething(String name) {

        if( Object.ReferenceEquals( name, SpecialValue1 ) ) {



        } else if( Object.ReferenceEquals( name, SpecialValue2 ) {


        } else {

        }
    }

    public void UsageExample() {

        DoSomething( SpecialValue1 );
        DoSomething( "some arbitrary value" );
    }
}
```

I want to know if this technique, using empty strings and object reference equality will always be safe, especially with respect to string interning.

Comment: Have you even tried `ReferenceEquals(SpecialValue1, SpecialValue2)`? Stings that appear directly in the source code (and other strings, by some algorithm) are subject to [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). So this is very different from e.g. `public static readonly object SpecialValue1 = new object(); public static readonly object SpecialValue2 = new object();`.

Comment: An overload that takes an object or enum is the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Antimony is right about the reasons this will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16631840/11173).

I would suggest that you define a type for the argument. Let's call it `ExampleArgument`.

```
public class ExampleArgument
{
    private readonly int _knownValue;
    private readonly string _arbitraryValue;

    public ExampleArgument(string arbitraryValue)
    {
        _arbitraryValue = arbitraryValue;
        _knownValue = 0;
    }

    private ExampleArgument(int knownValue)
    {
        _knownValue = knownValue;
        _arbitraryValue = null;
    }

    public static readonly ExampleArgument FirstKnownValue = new ExampleArgument(1);
    public static readonly ExampleArgument SecondKnownValue = new ExampleArgument(2);

    // obvious Equals and GetHashCode overloads

    // possibly other useful methods that depend on the application
}
```

Oh, and if you really want the calling syntax in your example, you could add:

```
    public static implicit operator ExampleArgument(string arbitraryValue)
    {
        return new ExampleArgument(arbitraryValue);
    }
```

Which is an implicit conversion operator from string to `ExampleArgument`.

```
DoSomething(ExampleArgument.FirstKnownValue);
DoSomething(new ExampleArgument("hello"));
DoSomething("hello"); // equivalent to previous line, uses implicit conversion operator
```

Comment: I went with this approach in the end - and it actually turned out to be the best decision as I needed polymorphic behaviour with those `ExampleArgument` types.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not safe. In fact, this will never work. String literals get interned, so both special values will have the same reference. Most compilers will also intern compile time constant strings, and you can always intern strings manually.

Unfortunately, if you want to accept any valid string, you need some other way to pass extra information. And even if a hack like this worked, it would be a bad idea, since it violates normal string equality semantics.

Here are the possibilities I can think of

- If you only have one special value, you can use null
- Take a broader type such as Object as input
- Take two parameters
- Make a separate function